# How to get text at specific value in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file with the following content:

```
<option>
      <test attr="a">text1</test>
      <test attr="b">text2</test>
      <test attr="c">text3</test>
</option>
```

How can I now extract text2 using xslt?
Everything I try gives me text1.

For example:

```
<xsl:if test="option/test/@attr='a'">
<xsl:value-of select="option/test"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath should get you the text2 value:

```
option/test[@attr='b']
```

It effectively says "select the test element that has an attr attribute with a value of 'b'".

So you could use it like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="option/test[@attr='b']"/>
```

without the need for the `xsl:if`.

Comment: That will find `<test>` elements anywhere in the document, not just those which are children of the `<option>` element. Generally, // is overkill unless you really do want a global search.

Comment: @keshlam while that is very true, and a good point, considering that the OP states this is the content of their XML I felt that it was allowable in this case. It's the predicate that is the point I am trying to get across, hence the explanation.

Comment: Since the OP doesn't know how to use a predicate I think it would be safe to assume they wouldn't know the issues with using the double slashes either. In that case I would either clearly state what that is doing or use a more efficient XPath. We don't want them to learn bad habits.

Comment: @MatthewGreen Very fair point - I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a predicate to specify "the `test` whose `attr` has the value 'a'".

```
 option/test[@attr='a']
```

You also need to be aware of the difference between relative and absolute xpaths, and know what context you're invoking the path from -- you are using relative paths which will work only if your current node is the `option`'s parent.

Comment: Your XPath will select the element with `text1`, not the element with `text2` as required by the OP.

Comment: The OP's question referred to both 'a' and text2. Rather that waste time reconciling that, I flipped a coin and trusted that if I was wrong the relevant change was obvious.